# Why does this code not function correctly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently trying to learn Ajax and have been following a tutorial. I have created the following script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function MyFunction(){

    var xmlhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

            document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "command.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<button onclick="MyFunction()">Execute</button>

<div id="MyDiv"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I then have a php file named command.php which just echos the word "success".

Obviously the intended purpose of this script is to return the word "success" when the execute button is clicked. I have followed the tutorial for this very precisely, so I'm unsure of what's wrong with what I've written.

I've also looked at other Ajax tutorials, to see what they might have done differently. It seems that some variants of Ajax look very different to others. I mean by this, a lot of tutorials involve code looking like what I've written, but many others (such as [this one](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php)) look rather different and involve many '$' signs. Why is this?

Comment: This tutorial must be very old. The fallback using `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` is only needed for Internet Explorer 6 and before. I'd skip it and just use XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: Try to do it through `jQuery` that's easy and better way to do it...!

Comment: this an example of AJAX request http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post

Comment: The '$' you keep seeing is a little library called [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Comment: Wow, those tutorials must have been early 2000's. You tagged jQuery, so why not just use it? And $ is just shorthand instead of having to type jQuery to use it.

Comment: Have you tried setting break points in your code to see what the return value from the ajax call is? Are you certain the server is responding correctly?

Comment: You don't *need* jQuery to do it. If you're learning, use plain JavaScript. It's almost as easy and very lightweight, while jQuery is a big library. If you're going to build a real website and you decide to use jQuery anyway (for other stuff too), you can always use jQuery's features, but make sure to learn the plain way too. [Vanilla-js.com shows how to do it](http://vanilla-js.com/) (scroll down) in jQuery and in plain 'vanilla' JavaScript.

Comment: `if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){` should be `if( xmlhttp.readyState == 4){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like maybe a copy/paste error. I'm guessing:

```
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
```

should be:

```
   if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
```

Also, it doesn't sound like you're using your browsers dev tools. The console should have a message like this in it:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxRequest is not defined
```

I suggest reading up on the dev tools for your preferred browser.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. The only question now is whether this is the right way of doing things? Unbeknown to me before people mentioned it here, the tutorial I am using seems to be very outdated. Do I need to learn a new method of doing this?

Comment: This is the right way if you don't want to depend on any external JavaScript libraries at all. If you don't mind taking a dependency on something like `jQuery` then I would recommend reading up on and using jQuerys `$.ajax` method.